# Fetching a list from a website using beautifulsoup in a dataframe column

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to fetch the keywords from the article website. The website keywords look like this:

```
`This is the link:` `https://www.horizont.net/marketing/nachrichten/bgh-haendler-haftet-nicht-fuer-kundenbewertungen-auf-amazon-180980`
```

[image]

I am using this to fetch the keywords:

```
   Article_Keyword = bs.find('div', {'class':'ListTags'}).get_text()
```

and this is how what i am getting:

```
Themen Bundesgerichtshof Amazon Verband Sozialer Wettbewerb Kundenbewertung Tape dpa
```

I need to get it by separating each keyword by comma. I can do it by RE but some keywords are with more than one word so i need that as one keyword.

is there any way to get each keyword by separating with comma?

Comment: You should lookup for a elements under your Article_keyword. Not sure this work, Article_Keyword.find_all("a")

Comment: It will work i guess also but i need a separator between them like coma

Comment: it will be a list, can do ",".join() to get elements in list as string separated by ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a child class element to Identify each element separately. I hope the below code helps.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from requests import get
url = "https://www.horizont.net/marketing/nachrichten/bgh-haendler-haftet-nicht-fuer-kundenbewertungen-auf-amazon-180980"
clnt = get(url)
page=soup(clnt.text,"html.parser")
data = page.find('div', attrs={'class':'ListTags'})
data1 = [ele.text for ele in data.find_all('a',attrs={'class':'PageArticle_keyword'})]
print(data1)
print(",".join(data1))
```

Output:

```
>> ['Bundesgerichtshof', 'Amazon', 'Verband Sozialer Wettbewerb', 'Kundenbewertung', 'Tape', 'dpa']
>> Bundesgerichtshof,Amazon,Verband Sozialer Wettbewerb,Kundenbewertung,Tape,dpa
```

Make sure you approve the answer if usefull.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.horizont.net/marketing/nachrichten/bgh-haendler-haftet-nicht-fuer-kundenbewertungen-auf-amazon-180980'
page = requests.get(url)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

Article_Keyword = soup1.find('div',{'class':'ListTags'}).find_all("a")
Article_Keyword = ", ".join([keyword.text.strip() for keyword in Article_Keyword])

print(Article_Keyword)
```

Comment: This will fails IF spaceblank in tag word

Comment: no. it will not fail, that case does not happen here. a blank tag will not appear in the string.

Comment: I means tag "Hello word" will be splited "Hello", "world" and desired is "one tag", "Hello World", "more tag"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Article_Keyword = bs.find('div', {'class':'ListTags'})
aes_Article_Keyword  = Article_Keyword.find_all("a")

s_Article_Keyword = ", ".join([x.text for x in aes_Article_Keyword])
```